# How to keep Form_Current actions from triggering table validation errors?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table `T` with a required text field `item`, and a text field `userID` that is meant to fill in the current user's login ID.  I have a form `mainForm` with a subform `TForm` based on this table.  To make sure that each record has the user's ID I have added the following event to `TForm`:

```
Sub form_current()
 Me.userID = Environ("username")
End Sub
```

When I open `mainForm`, I get this error message immediately on opening:

```
You must enter a value in the 'T.item' field.
```

I think what is happening here is that the `form_current()` event makes Access think that I've attempted to complete entry of a new record while `T.item` is still blank, which violates a table constraint because that's a required field.  Curiously, though, this only happens when I open `mainForm`; when I open `TForm` by itself, I don't get this error message on opening.

Should I be using a different event to fill in the user's login ID for each field?  Or is there a better way to use `form_current()` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way.**

Create a function in a module:

```
Public Function getUserName() As String
    getUserName = Environ("Username")
End Function
```

Then open property window for your TForm, select "userId" field, select "Data" tab in property window, find row with "Default Value" and put next expression: =getUserName().

I don't know why but access don't see Environ() function.

**Second way.**

Implement OnLoad event like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.userID.DefaultValue = "=""" & Environ("username") & """"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I went with the second way and it solved the problem.